# Show week number and year of date

Tags: vba, date

I am making a code that shows the date, user, week number and year when a user says 'yes' in row 34.

So far I managed the date and username to reveal, but I am having trouble with the weeknumber and year (which for some reason keeps saying 1899). Can you help me out?

This is what I got:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   
    If Target.Column = 34 Then
        Select Case Target
            Case "Yes", "yes"
                Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
                Target.Offset(0, 2) = Application.UserName
                Target.Offset(0, 4) = WeekNum
                Target.Offset(0, 6) = Year(date_value)


            Case vbNullString
                Range("AI" & Target.Row & ":AJ" & Target.Row).ClearContents


        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use worksheetfunction as if you were using them in excel cells like this for the weeknum:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 34 Then
        Select Case Target
            Case "Yes", "yes"
                Target.Offset(0, 1) = Date
                Target.Offset(0, 2) = Application.UserName
                Target.Offset(0, 4) = Application.IsoWeekNum(Date)
                Target.Offset(0, 6) = Year(Date)
            Case vbNullString
                Range("AI" & Target.Row & ":AJ" & Target.Row).ClearContents
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

You couldn't get the year because you have no variable called `date_value` you need to use `Date` (to refer to today's date) or build your date in a  `Date` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess with `Target.Offset(0, 4) = WeekNum` you are trying to use the Excel built in function WEEKNUM?
Then you would approach writing the week number like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub showdate()
    Dim a As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

    Set a = ws.Range("A1")

    a.Value = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now, vbMonday)
End Sub
```

`Now` is specifically the date of execution, of course you should replace it with the variable that holds the date you want to operate on.
The year can be displayed like this:

```
    Dim b As Range
    Set b = ws.Range("A2")
    b.Value = Year(Now)
```

This gives me this output:

[image]